# Magento install on MacOs: Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config

Tags: php, installation, magento2, phpcodesniffer

I was trying to install Magento 2 on MacOS 10.15 using https://alpineinc.com/2020/05/install-magento-2-locally-on-a-mac/.
I use the command:

`php composer.phar create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2 --ignore-platform-reqs`

but I receive: `Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config`.

I tried with `php composer.phar global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*` and `brew install php-code-sniffer`, but I get the same error.